# Simple Graph question

Tags: graph-theory

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me answer the following questions:

This is a true or false question. Select the true option if the following statement is true and the false option otherwise.

“There exists a simple graph (a graph without parallel edges or loops) that has the following vertices

one vertex with degree 6,
two vertices with degree 5,
one vertex with degree 3,
two vertices with degree 2,
and one vertex with degree 1."

I've tried to research how to drive the answers or methodology to use however, but I still can't seem to answer the question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198636/question-about-simple-graph

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986178/a-simple-problem-of-graph-theory-about-the-degree-of-vertices

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732079/does-there-exist-a-simple-graph-with-the-degree-sequence

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664638/drawing-a-simple-graph-with-six-vertices-and-varying-degrees

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065908/drawing-a-simple-graph-from-known-degrees

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2245715/proof-of-simple-graph-using-vertex-degrees